# Why is my Convnet essentially just learning the mean of all the y_values?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, image-recognition

I have a fairly simple convolutional network, and it is essentially just learning the mean of all the y_values. For each piece of datum, irregardless of the input, it is outputting the same thing. Does anyone know what is going on?

[output of the model.predict function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcF8c.png)

[model.compile and model.fit function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bqqp5.png)

[the mean and the pre-processing for the actual outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51zM1.png)

Comment: Please add the code instead of the image, as per StackOverflow's rules.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your model is not learning so the final layer is just biased to the most likely outcome.  Essentially it is just picking the average value.  From my experience this typically means either your learning rate is too high, or you model is too deep and the gradients can't get through.  Try reducing the learning rate.  It's hard to give better advice since you didn't post code.